# Copy only part of a binary file in C++

Tags: c++

This is a nice and intuitive way to copy files:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream  src("from.bn", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream  dst("to.bn",   std::ios::binary);

    dst << src.rdbuf();
}
```

How can one modify it in order to just copy the first *n* bytes of `src`?

Comment: `.rdbuf()` copies everything. You'll need to use binary read/write APIs for anything else.

Comment: Resolution is generally measured in *bytes* (not *bits*). What architecture do you want to support where you can write, for instance, 3 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first *n* **characters**, you can use:

```
std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(src), n, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(dst));
```

Comment: I would very much like this to be the correct answer, but unfortunately, I get a runtime error that the istreambuf_iterator is not dereferenceable.

Comment: @FrustratedSoul, this is working for me. See for instance: https://godbolt.org/z/TdaGnq9Gb, could you give more details about the precise code?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure that their will be 'enough' data in the input stream, you can use `readsome()` to get what's there, up to a given limit (if you know there will be a big enough input stream, just use `read`):

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t amount = 4242;
    char data[amount];
    std::ifstream  src("from.bn", std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream  dst("to.bn", std::ios::binary);

    size_t actual = src.readsome(data, amount);
    dst.write(data, actual);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `readsome` is a bit more complicated than you make out. e.g. read notes under https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.read()` method of std::ifstream, which enables you to read N bytes of data. 
To be fully changeable, you can add a call to `.seekg()`, to move into the file.